# Deleting /usr/loca/pgsql before reinstalling postgres

Tags: postgresql, homebrew

I've uninstalled postgres by running `make uninstall` and `make clean` and I want to reinstall it using homebrew this time, however, I noticed that my `/usr/local/pgsql` directory is still there.  Should I delete this before doing a homebrew postgres install?